# Printing file paths using bash

Tags: bash, unix, directory, pwd

I am a student learning bash. I am currently trying to print a series of absolute file paths to run additional scripts with.

Currently `echo $PWD, *In` does not work.
My file structure looks like.

```
/home/hayden/myProject/gene
```

within this directory there are several folders but I am specifically interested in three.

```
/largeIn/
/mediumIn/
/smallIn/
```

Within these folders there are differently named files that all end with `.fa`.

Is there a simple way to extract the files paths to a txt file?

to looks like this

```
/home/hayden/myProject/gene/largeIn/file.fa
/home/hayden/myProject/gene/mediumIn/file.fa
/home/hayden/myProject/gene/smallIn/file.fa
```

Thank you

EDIT: @Afle solution was successful.

Comment: Maybe `ls $PWD/*In/*.fa`?

Comment: If the task is not especially using `bash` for this, I'd propose to use the Unix tool `find`:  `find /home/hayden/myProject/gene/ -name '*.fa'`.

Comment: Your question is how to **find** the paths or how to **extract** them?

Comment: It is to extract to them

Comment: Thank Alfe. Your solution works! There is so much in the command line tooldbox I had no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the standard Linux [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) utility.  It will be your friend when you are working with any shell, not just bash.  It's a general utility for finding files recursively within directories.

In your particular case, you'd do something like :

find /home/hayden/myProject/gene -name '*.fa'

This will find *any* files under /home/hayden/myProject/gene whose names end with ".fa"  (even if they are multiple levels below "gene".

Now, if you know fr a fact that files are exactly where your examples are you could simply use bash's [glob'ing](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) and refer to them as :

/home/hayden/myProject/gene/*In/file.fa